# how to add 1 item to every single array in an array of arrays

Tags: php, associative-array

I know the problem can be solved using foreach, but I wonder if there is another way of doing this in fewer lines.

ex:

```
$arr1 = [
  ['example1'=>'ex1','example2'=>'ex2','example3'=>'ex3'],
  ['example4'=>'ex4','example5'=>'ex5','example6'=>'ex6'],
  ['example7'=>'ex7','example8'=>'ex8','example9'=>'ex9'],
]:

$arr2 = ['example'=>'examplelist'];
```

wanted results:

```
$result =  [
  ['example1'=>'ex1','example2'=>'ex2','example3'=>'ex3','example'=>'examplelist'],
  ['example4'=>'ex4','example5'=>'ex5','example6'=>'ex6','example'=>'examplelist'],
  ['example7'=>'ex7','example8'=>'ex8','example9'=>'ex9','example'=>'examplelist'],
]:
```

Comment: You want to append to every element of the array without iterating over it?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I believe he's asking for a way with built in functions.

Comment: @El_Vanja You mean loops?

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I mean without explicitly defining any loops. Stuff like `array_map` or `array_walk`.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Yes I want to append $arr2 to  all my records in $arr1

Comment: You could go with `array_walk()` but this will not save any lines. Also I do not think it is a reasonable goal to do anything with "fewer lines".